# x265 Encoder: order of values in 'planes' array

Tags: c++, encoding, h.265, libx265

During the encoding process with x265 encoder (https://x265.readthedocs.org/en/default/api.html) I want to write image pixel values (specifically values of Y channel) into .txt file after a new image is encoded (not important why). For that, I'm using 'planes' variable of class x265_picture:

```
x265_picture* pic_out; # variable where encoded image is to be stored 
... # encoding process
uint8_t *plane = (uint8_t*)pic_out->planes[0]; 
uint32_t pixelCount = x265_picturePlaneSize(pic_out->colorSpace, m_param->sourceWidth, m_param->sourceHeight, 0);
ofstream out_file("out_file.txt");

for (uint32_t j = 0; j < pixelCount; j++) # loop for all pixels
{
    int pix_val = plane[j];
    out << pix_val;
}

ofstream.close()
```

But when I reconstruct the output data into image, I get

[image]

instead of

[image]

or another example:

[image]

instead of

[image]

(color is not important, the "stripes" are the concern)

In the output file there seem to be intervals of data in (apparently) correct order (let's say 89,90,102,98,...) followed always by long sequence of equal numbers (eg. 235,235,235,235... or 65,65,65,65...), that "create" the stripes. Could someone please tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: Where are you getting the x265_picturePlaneSize function? I don't see it in the header.

Comment: haven't used this for a while, but it is located in x265/source/common/common.cpp

Comment: its definition: uint32_t x265_picturePlaneSize(int csp, int width, int height, int plane)
{
    uint32_t size = (uint32_t)(width >> x265_cli_csps[csp].width[plane]) * (height >> x265_cli_csps[csp].height[plane]);

    return size;
}

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks guys, just solved this...the key is using 'src += srcStride':

```
ofstream out_file("out_file.txt");
int srcStride = pic_out->stride[0] / sizeof(pixel);
uint8_t* src = (uint8_t*) pic_out->planes[0];

for (int y = 0; y < m_param->sourceHeight; y++, src += srcStride)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < m_param->sourceWidth; x++)
        out_file << (int)(src[x]) << ",";
}
out_file.close();
```